# Rubber Nginx Passenger deployment 'passenger' was not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, amazon-ec2, passenger

someone is getting this error on the log trying to deploy on ec2?

```
 ** [out :: db01.y.com] libgdbm-dev is already the newest version.
 ** [out :: db01.y.com] libgdbm3 is already the newest version.
 ** [out :: db01.y.com] libncurses5-dev is already the newest version.
 ** [out :: db01.y.com] libreadline6-dev is already the newest version.
 ** [out :: db01.y.com] zlib1g-dev is already the newest version.
 ** [out :: db01.y.com] collectd is already the newest version.
 ** [out :: db01.y.com] monit is already the newest version.
 ** [out :: db01.y.com] ec2-ami-tools is already the newest version.
 ** [out :: db01.y.com] build-essential is already the newest version.
 ** [out :: app01.y.com] 
 ** [out :: app01.y.com] Reading state information...
 ** [out :: app01.y.com] 
 ** [out :: app01.y.com] E: Version '1:4.0.59-1~precise1' for 'passenger' was not found
```

my passenger_nginx, so have some specific version to this passenger_ngnix?

```
 passenger_version: '1:4.0.59-1~`lsb_release -sc`1'
    passenger_ruby: "#{ruby_path}/bin/ruby"
    nginx_log_dir: /mnt/nginx/logs
    use_ssl_key: false
    roles:
      passenger_nginx:
        packages: [libcurl4-openssl-dev, libpcre3-dev, nginx-extras, [passenger, "#{passenger_version}"]]
```

Comment: Do you have to use that passenger version? If so, try adding to your Gemfile `gem 'passenger', '1:4.0.59-1~precise1'`

Comment: for me does not matter wich version, any that works and don't give problem.

Comment: so i installed the last and the same problem happens

Comment: E: Version '5.0.15' for 'passenger' was not found

Comment: What's in your Gemfile?

Comment: group :production do
  gem "pg"
  gem 'passenger'  
end


#gem 'debugger'



gem 'rubber'
gem 'open4'

Comment: Looks fine. Try looking into the Capfile and Gemfile here at the [example project](https://github.com/dliggat/bloggy). Try having `require 'rubber'` before the production group.

Comment: thank's man, but still the same